# Setting Redshift Isolation Level

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm attempting to set the isolation level in redshift and I'm getting an error that there are users connected.

```
Database "db" is being accessed by other users,so the database isolation level cannot be altered.
```

I (superuser) have tried setting the db connection limit to 0, done a soft_reboot, killed pids manually, but that error persists. Has anyone tried this successfully? Below is my last code block:

```
ALTER DATABASE db CONNECTION LIMIT 0 ; -- no non-superuser conns
ALTER USER etl_user NOCREATEUSER; -- stop etl superuser conns
SELECT reboot_cluster();
ALTER DATABASE BI ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT; -- why not try here
SELECT * FROM SVV_TRANSACTIONS; -- catch any other pids
-- terminate all pids
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(...);

ALTER DATABASE BI ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT; -- set new snapshot isolation
ALTER USER etl_user CREATEUSER; -- restore etl superuser conns
ALTER DATABASE db CONNECTION LIMIT UNLIMITED; -- restore non-superuser conns
```

Comment: Your issue might be that you were checking `SVV_TRANSACTIONS` and not `STV_SESSIONS`; I had no problem with setting connection limit to 0 (thanks for that step!), then doing `pg_terminate_backend()` for `SELECT process FROM STV_SESSIONS WHERE dbname='db' AND user != 'myuser'`, after which `ALTER DB` succeeded and I only needed to revert the connection limit

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.

I resolved using using the below techniques

1. Pause your cluster
2. Restart your cluster
3. While it is restarting, run your alter
   ALTER DATABASE BI ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT;

Your alter might fail at some time, but when you hit alter at the right time( Before user starts using it) you will be able to run your alter command successfully.

I had also scheduled this query after every 1 min so that it get executed in the background. When my cluster was up and running, after some time I disabled the scheduled query... Hope this trick will help.. It has the disadvantage of having downtime so use this method with care.